# How can I trigger my login modal (popover) when authentication is required?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm building a Rails 4 app and using Devise for authentication. When the user attempts to access a URL that requires authentication, Devise redirects the user to login page to create a new session.

I decided to complicate things by configuring Devise to handle AJAX login requests and allowing the user to login through a modal form. Its works great so far. When the user taps on the 'Login' button in the nav bar, the modal is displayed, the user enters their credentials, the AJAX request is processed, and the modal is dismissed.

However, the modal login form can ONLY be triggered by clicking on the 'Login' button in my nav bar. Whenever the user attempts to access a URL that requires authentication, the user is still redirected to the Devise login page. Instead of being redirected to the login page, I would like the login modal to be displayed. **How can I trigger my login modal (popover) when authentication is required?**

Here's an overview of how I'm currently triggering my login modal. I'm using [leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/) as my modal...

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
});
```

Which is triggered by clicking on the Login button in my nav bar...

```
<%= link_to "Login", "#modal", class: "sign-up", id: "modal_trigger" %>
```

And here's the modal view...

```
<div class="user_login">
    <%= form_for resource, 
           as: resource_name,   
           url: session_path(resource_name),
           html: {id: "sign_in_user"},
           remote: true do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
      <br/>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
        <div class="checkbox">
              <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label "Remember me on this computer" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit "Login", class: "btn btn_red" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your wisdom! Please let me know if I need to post more code.

Answer (score 4):

Based on one of the following preference :

1. **I Wanna User to hit the target page then show the modal**
2. **I Wanna the login modal show first then redirect the user after signup**

**For Preference one**

1- first skip the before_filter authentication in the controllers you want to open public for users

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

2- create a partial which triggers the modal if the user is not signed in

```
- unless user_signed_in?
  :javascript
   $(function loginModalShow(){
     $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
   });
```

3- render the partial at the end of ure view

```
= render partial: "partial_name"
```

**For Preference two**

1. Add an application helper to trigger the modal

   ```
   def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
     html_options, options, name = options, name, block if block_given?
     options ||= {}
     html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)
     url = url_for(options)
     html_options['href'] ||= url if url.present?
     if html_options["require_login"] and not logged_in?
       html_options.delete "data-toggle"
       html_options.delete "data-remote"
       html_options.delete "data-target"
       html_options.delete "data-method"
       html_options['href'] = '#'
       html_options['onclick'] = "loginModalShow();"
       html_options['class'] = "" if html_options['class'].nil?
       html_options['class'] = html_options['class']
     end
     content_tag(:a, name || url, html_options, &block)
   end
   ```
2. Then on each link you want to trigger the login model, add the following

   ```
      link_to your_path, require_login: true
   ```
3. create a partial which triggers the modal if the user is not signed in

   - unless user_signed_in?
     :javascript
      $(function loginModalShow(){
        $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
      });
4. In your application layout add the following

   ```
     = render partial: "partial_name"
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Kimooz. I don't quite follow, a few questions: 1) In step 1, are you saying I should skip the authentication check on pages that don't require authentication? That doesn't make sense to me. 2) In step 3, are you saying I should render the partial in the views that require authentication? That also doesn't make sense since the user needs to be first authenticated before loading that view. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kimooz This is just perfect. I was looking for this for like centuries :)